# in R: how to get result of an operation evaluated in specified environment

Tags: r

In R, suppose you have an environment "big.env" containing a large data frame "big.df" and you want to retrieve a small subset from "big.df".

You could do the following in the interactive/global enviroment:

```
  big.df = get("big.df", envir = big.env)
  my.subset = subset(big.df, my.index.table==desired.subset.value)
```

Is there a way to do the sub-setting AND the retrieval from "big.env" in a single step?

My failed attempts are shown below:

```
  my.subset = eval("subset(big.df, my.index.table==desired.subset.value)", envir = big.env)
  my.subset = eval(as.expression("subset(big.df, my.index.table==desired.subset.value))", envir = big.env)
  my.subset = eval(expression("subset(big.df, my.index.table==desired.subset.value))", envir = big.env)
```

More generally, is there a way to execute an instruction within an environment and get the result into the current/global environment? For instance, get the colnames of big.df in example above by something like:

```
  my.colnames = eval(as.expression("colnames(big.df)", envir = big.env)
```

Comment: I would guess `my.subset = evalq(subset(big.df, my.index.table==desired.subset.value), envir = big.env)` but it would help to have a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) in your question to test with. It's not clear where `desired.subset.value` is defined.

Comment: Yes, evalq does work.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Refer to it as `big.env$big.df` .  For example, using the built-in six row data frame, `BOD` we create a test environment `e` containing twice `BOD` and then extract the rows whose `Time` values are greater than the mean `Time`:

```
e <- local({ BOD2 <- 2 * BOD; environment() }) # test data

subset(e$BOD2, Time > mean(Time))
```

giving:

```
  Time demand
4    8   32.0
5   10   31.2
6   14   39.6
```

**2)** `with` is another approach:

```
with(e, subset(BOD2, Time > mean(Time)))
```

or

```
subset(with(e, BOD2), Time > mean(Time))
```